# bindPopup with dynamic content from geojson

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I am attempting to .bindPopup to my geoJson layer with dynamic content based on properties within the geoJson. Currently, my popup does not show on click. The content is later added to mymap even though that is not shown.

```
var QueensAssemblyDistricts = L.geoJSON(AssemblyDistricts, {
  style: assemblystyle,
  onEachFeature: assemblyOnEachFeature
});

function assemblyOnEachFeature(feature, QueensAssemblyDistricts) {
  QueensAssemblyDistricts.bindPopup(feature.properties.AssemDist);
}

function assemblystyle() {
  return {
    fillColor: "#bd95c1",
    fillOpacity: .02,
    color: "#2b2e5e",
    weight: 2,
  };
}
```

Comment: please provide the geojson code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, by adding string in front of the (feature.properties.AssemDist) within the .bindpopup method  it allowed the information to pull in from the geojson. Not sure why that happened.